# Ruby-ize for loop - counting all the n-digit numbers that contain the digit 5 anywhere

Tags: algorithm, ruby, mathematics

I wrote this a while back when my fiance was taking a Number Theory class. I wrote about it [here](http://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/how-many-numbers-less-than-ten-thousand-contain-a-five/) and it recently came back to my attention. Anytime I write a `for` loop in Ruby I feel kind of dirty. I would like to "Ruby-ize" this routine if there is a more Ruby way to do it. Also, is this the most efficient algorithm for this?

Original Problem:

> How many numbers less than 10000 that contain the digit 5 anywhere?

(Even thought the original problem was for < 10000, I've run this much farther out)

The algorithm:

> \$f(x) = 9y + \dfrac{x}{10}\$
>
> Where \$y\$ is the previous result and \$x\$ is the power of 10 we're checking against.
>
> i.e. \$y = 1\$ and \$x = 100\$, or \$y = 19\$ and \$x = 1000\$

or, for the more mathematically inclined

> \$f(10^n)=9f(10^{n-1})+10^{n-1}\$

The code:

```
def numbersContaining5(pwr)
# Prints on screen the count of numbers containing a "5"
#    for each power of ten up and including the one passed in.
# pwr = the power of ten you wish to calculate to

    prev = 0
    for i in 1..pwr
        prev = (prev*9) + (10**i)/10 
        puts prev
    end
end

#call function
numbersContaining5(4) # 10^4 = 10000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that using recursion is wrong, but there is already an abstraction for what this algorithm does: a left fold (`Enumerable#reduce`):

```
def number_containing_5(power)
  (1..power).reduce(0) { |acc, n| (9*acc) + (10**n)/10 }
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I would use recurence in place of the loop - it is easier to understand the logic behind it then:

```
def number_containing_5(pwr)
  return 0 if pwr == 0
  number_containing_5(pwr-1) * 9 + 10**(pwr-1)
end
```

Comment: I never even considered recursion. Nice call. Are the underscores a Ruby convention? Should I not use camel case?

Comment: @ckuhn203 - That's correct. There is no lower camelCase in ruby, upper CamelCase is used for constants. Some developers like dividing constants from classes, by using UPPERCASE_NOTATION for constants and CamelCase for classes and modules (this is however quite artificial, as classes are just constants).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll read up on the style conventions.

Comment: I suggest changing the base case to `return 0 if pwr == 0`.

Comment: For those that prefer pure expressions to imperative returns: `pwr == 0 ? 0 : number_containing_5(pwr-1) * 9 + 10**(pwr-1)` (or with `if`/`else`)

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out there is a better algorithm for this. The algorithm is \$10^n - 9^n\$ and you can find an explanation of it over on [Mathematics Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/820519/155159). The improved algorithm completely removed my need for a loop, so I separated the test (printing) logic from the actual function and "ruby-ized" that loop instead.

```
def count_of_numbers_containing_5(power)
  (10**power)-(9**power)
end 

def test_it(pwr)
  (1..pwr).each {|i| puts count_of_numbers_containing_5(i)}
end

test_it 20
```

Comment: `10 ** n - 9 ** n` is a good solution for Ruby, where integers are unbounded. Be careful, though, with languages where ints can overflow, where the recursive solution may be better.

Comment: The reason this works is straightforward: there are 10^n numbers with n or fewer digits when the digits are drawn from the 10 digits 0-9, whereas there are 9^n  numbers with n or fewer digits when the digits are drawn from the 9 digits 0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9. The difference is therefore the number of numbers with n or fewer digits that contain one or more 5's.

Answer (score 3):

this isn't exactly using your algorithm, but I think this does the trick.

```
(1..10000).select { |number| number.to_s.split('').any?{ |s| s == '5' } }
```

Comment: That is *absolutely* more ruby, but it's also brute force  isn't it?

Comment: Benchmark it vs your algorithm.  If the difference isn't that much, then I'd argue that more clear code is a better solution.  But if you need to optimize, I fully understand.  But yeah benchmark it and find out.  I would use https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips rather than the stdlib benchmark as it provides a bit more information.

Comment: Benchmarking is kind of moot. For 10^4 (10,000) I loop 4 times. This will roughly loop (10^4)*(5!) times. Nice answer though.

Comment: Oh Somehow I misread the question, I thought you wanted all numbers with the 5 in it, not just how many there were.  Yeah definitely use the above algorithms for that.  this is if you actually want to do something with all those numbers.